# jQuery hover over not working properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-animate, jquery-hover

What I want to do is image to move right when mouse hovers over it and come back to the same position when mouse is taken off the image. But what this is doing is the image goes to the left and disappears when mouse hovers over it. Please tell me what my mistake is.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
      img { position: relative; 
      }
    </style>

    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js" type = "text/javascript"></script>
    <script type = "text/javascript">
    $('#box img').hover(
      function () {
        $(this).animate({
          right: '2px'
        });
      }, 
      function () {
        $(this).animate({
          left: '2px'
        });
      }
    );
    </script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id = "box">
      <img src="pathtimage/1.jpg" hspace="30"  height="350" width="220" >
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: The code needs to be wrapped in `$(document).ready()`.  It is executing before the elements are loaded on the DOM.

Comment: I am sorry I am new to this. How do I do it? Where shoud I put $(document).ready()

Answer (score 4, accepted):

jQuery's `animate()` animates CSS properties, so you should probably stick with animating the same property, as `left` and `right` are two different CSS properties

```
$(function() {
    $('#box img').hover(function () {
        $(this).animate({
            left: '2px'
        }, 600);
    }, function () {
        $(this).animate({
            left: '0px'
        }, 600);
    });
});
```

Also note that in some cases you have to set an inital value in CSS, as jQuery can't compute default values like `inherit` or `auto`, and that setting left and top values doesn't work without a position

```
#box img {position: relative; left: 0}
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/wVzEG/1/)

Comment: when I changed the code to this, it has stopped moving image at all.the image is static now and not moving

Comment: @user2942227 - I'm not sure what the problem could be. The code in the question shouldn't work at all, and this code works just fine for me, the only thing I can think of is that you have CSS or javascript somewhere else that is also affecting the image.

Comment: <head> <style>
#box img {position: relative; left: 0;}
</style>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js" type = "text/javascript"></script>
<script type = "text/javascript">
$('#box img').hover(function () {
    $(this).animate({
        left: '20px'
    },1000);
}, function () {
    $(this).animate({
        left: '0px'
    },1000);
});




</script>
</head>


<body>
 
<div id = "box">

<img src="/Users/Rohit/Desktop/ThinkBig-BobbleHead/Ryan2.jpg" hspace="30"  height="350" width="220" >

</div>
 
</body>
</html>

Comment: @user2942227 - That's neither the code in the answer nor the posted Fiddle, that's pretty much the same code you where using in the question. Use the code in the Fiddle above, just change the image source

Answer (score 1):

The code needs to be wrapped in $(document).ready(). It is executing before the elements are loaded on the DOM. `$(document).ready(function(){})` tells jQuery to wait until the DOM is loaded before executing your script.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('#box img').hover(
      function () {
        $(this).animate({
          right: '2px'
        });
      }, 
      function () {
        $(this).animate({
          left: '2px'
        });
      }
    );
});
```